# Golang - How to chain together several channels?

Tags: go

Trying to schedule an item, send the item to a "status" channel to get the status then send the item to a "delete" channel to delete the item. I am setting the size of both channels and expected after the items are finished being deleted I would get to "done". It appears the code is stopping after the "delete" is performed right before getting to "done". Why do I get "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" right after "Delete Item" and before "Done" ? Which go routine is sleeping?

https://go.dev/play/p/W49niF5xngQ

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    numbers := []int{1, 2, 4}
    for _, n := range numbers {
        fmt.Printf("Schedule and delete %d items.\n", n)
        statusChan := make(chan string, n)
        deleteChan := make(chan string, n)
        done := make(chan bool)

        go func(n int, statusChan chan<- string) {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                i := i

                go func(n int, statusChan chan<- string) {
                    fmt.Printf("Scheduling item number ... %d\n", i)
                    itemNum := fmt.Sprintf("item_num_%d\n", i)
                    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
                    statusChan <- itemNum
                }(n, statusChan)
            }
        }(n, statusChan)

        go func(statusChan <-chan string, deleteChan chan<- string) {
            for itemNum := range statusChan {
                fmt.Printf("Checking status of item number ... %s\n", itemNum)
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
                deleteChan <- itemNum
            }
        }(statusChan, deleteChan)

        go func(deleteChan <-chan string, done chan<- bool) {
            for itemNum := range deleteChan {
                fmt.Printf("Delete item: %s", itemNum)
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Done with scheduling and deleting %d item.\n", n)
            done <- true
        }(deleteChan, done)
        <-done
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to pass `i` to your inner status function, not `n`, but it won't make any difference.  Why are you using the inner function?

Comment: @TimRoberts Some items might take longer to schedule than others so I put that go func inside of the for loop.

Comment: Yes, but why couldn't you just take all that code and run it in the outer statusChan function?  That's my point.  I don't think the inner func gains you anything at all.

Comment: In any case, the problem here is that all  your coroutines ARE asleep.  You seem to be assuming that the range loops will exit after they have fetched one item.  That's just not true.  Your "range" loops are all going to block forever, waiting for more input.    The number in the `make` call just tells how many things can be in the queue at any given time, NOT how many it can handle in its lifetime.  You need to have some kind of "all done" signal that propagates through the channels.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah yes I thought the reason for specifying the buffer value for the channel was to specify how many items to process then it would automatically close. Instead that value is max allowed at any given time so I have to signal when to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you were thinking.  I use "***" as an "all done" signal.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    numbers := []int{1, 2, 4}
    for _, n := range numbers {
        fmt.Printf("Schedule and delete %d items.\n", n)
        statusChan := make(chan string, n)
        deleteChan := make(chan string, n)
        done := make(chan bool)

        go func(n int, statusChan chan<- string) {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                fmt.Printf("Scheduling item number ... %d\n", i)
                itemNum := fmt.Sprintf("item_num_%d\n", i)
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
                statusChan <- itemNum
            }
            statusChan <- "***"
        }(n, statusChan)

        go func(statusChan <-chan string, deleteChan chan<- string) {
            for itemNum := range statusChan {
              fmt.Printf("Checking status of item number ... %s\n", itemNum)
              deleteChan <- itemNum
            }
        }(statusChan, deleteChan)

        go func(deleteChan <-chan string, done chan<- bool) {
            for itemNum := range deleteChan {
              if itemNum == "***" {
                break
              }
              fmt.Printf("Delete item: %s", itemNum)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Done with scheduling and deleting %d item.\n", n)
            done <- true
        }(deleteChan, done)
        <-done
    }
}
```